# Scipy.optimize.minimize method='SLSQP' ignores constraint

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I'm using SciPy for optimization and the method SLSQP seems to ignore my constraints.

Specifically, I want x[3] and x[4] to be in the range [0-1]

I'm getting the message: 'Inequality constraints incompatible'

Here is the results of the execution followed by an example code (uses a dummy function):

```
  status: 4
  success: False
njev: 2
nfev: 24
 fun: 0.11923608071680103
   x: array([-10993.4278558 , -19570.77080806, -23495.15914299, -26531.4862831 ,
     4679.97660534])
message: 'Inequality constraints incompatible'
 jac: array([ 12548372.4766904 ,  12967696.88362279,  39928956.72239509,
    -9224613.99092537,   3954696.30747453,         0.        ])
 nit: 2
```

Here is my code:

```
from random import random
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def func(x):
   """ dummy function to optimize """
   print 'x'+str(x)
   return random()

my_constraints = ({'type':'ineq', 'fun':lambda(x):1-x[3]-x[4]},
                  {'type':'ineq', 'fun':lambda(x):x[3]},
                  {'type':'ineq', 'fun':lambda(x):x[4]},
                  {'type':'ineq', 'fun':lambda(x):1-x[4]},
                  {'type':'ineq', 'fun':lambda(x):1-x[3]})

minimize(func, [57.9499 ,-18.2736,1.1664,0.0000,0.0765],
         method='SLSQP',constraints=my_constraints)
```

EDIT - 
The problem persists when even when removing the first constraint.

The problem persists when I try to use the *bounds* variables. 
i.e.,

```
bounds_pairs = [(None,None),(None,None),(None,None),(0,1),(0,1)]
minimize(f,initial_guess,method=method_name,bounds=bounds_pairs,constraints=non_negative_prob)
```

Comment: Why are you using a nonsensical function to optimize? If the function just returns `random()` (and in particular, doesn't even return consistent results for the same input), of course SciPy is going to get confused.

Comment: For the sake of the example. This problem occurs regardless of the function I use.  I don't think that's the problem @user2357112

Comment: At least in the scipy docs, when using a lambda they take pains to return an np.array(), like: ’fun’ : lambda x: np.array([x[0]**3 - x[1]]).

Comment: Thanks @JonCuster but this is not the case too. The problem persists whether I use np.array or just a sequence. I tried to have the minimal example that reproduces this issue.

Comment: It was worth a shot.  OK, lets look at the constraints. If you really just want what you stated, i.e. x[3] and x[4] be [0,1], why do you have the first constraint? You could just use the bounds option instead for that.

Comment: @JonCuster I actually need that constraint too.  Problem persists when I remove the first constraint. 
I also tried the bounds variable before with no luck!

Comment: So, thinking about it a bit more, one issue could be that your first constraint reduces the dimensionality of the problem - you could equally well replace x[4] with 1-x[3], and limit x[3] to [0,1]. This reduces the dimensionality of the problem, reduces the constraints to 3, and probably makes for a much happier algorithm.

Comment: I checked it. It's not that either. @JonCuster

Comment: Well, I'm pretty much out of ideas on my end. Sorry.

Comment: @Zahy I don't know if you are still active on SO, but I've done some digging on this question as it comes up on the "featured problems" on the SciPy tag. Have a look.

Answer (score 15):

I know this is a very old question, but I was intrigued.

## When does it happen?

This problem occurs when the optimisation function is not reliably differentiable. If you use a nice smooth function like this:

```
opt = numpy.array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2])

def func(x):
   return sum((x - opt)**2)
```

The problem goes away.

## How do I impose hard constraints?

Note that none of the constrained algorithms in `scipy.minimize` have guarantees that the function will never be evaluated outside the constraints. If this is a requirement for you, you should rather use transformations. So for instance to ensure that no negative values for x[3] are ever used, you can use a transformation `x3_real = 10^x[3]`. This way x[3] can be any value but the variable you use will never be negative.

## Deeper analysis

Investigating the Fortran code for slsqp yields the following insights into when this error occurs. The routine returns a `MODE` variable, which can take on these values:

```
C*        MODE = -1: GRADIENT EVALUATION, (G&A)                        *
C*                0: ON ENTRY: INITIALIZATION, (F,G,C&A)               *
C*                   ON EXIT : REQUIRED ACCURACY FOR SOLUTION OBTAINED *
C*                1: FUNCTION EVALUATION, (F&C)                        *
C*                                                                     *
C*                   FAILURE MODES:                                    *
C*                2: NUMBER OF EQUALITY CONTRAINTS LARGER THAN N       *
C*                3: MORE THAN 3*N ITERATIONS IN LSQ SUBPROBLEM        *
C*                4: INEQUALITY CONSTRAINTS INCOMPATIBLE               *
C*                5: SINGULAR MATRIX E IN LSQ SUBPROBLEM               *
C*                6: SINGULAR MATRIX C IN LSQ SUBPROBLEM               *
```

The part which assigns mode 4 (which is the error you are getting) is as follows:

```
C   SEARCH DIRECTION AS SOLUTION OF QP - SUBPROBLEM

      CALL dcopy_(n, xl, 1, u, 1)
      CALL dcopy_(n, xu, 1, v, 1)
      CALL daxpy_sl(n, -one, x, 1, u, 1)
      CALL daxpy_sl(n, -one, x, 1, v, 1)
      h4 = one
      CALL lsq (m, meq, n , n3, la, l, g, a, c, u, v, s, r, w, iw, mode)

C   AUGMENTED PROBLEM FOR INCONSISTENT LINEARIZATION

      IF (mode.EQ.6) THEN
          IF (n.EQ.meq) THEN
              mode = 4
          ENDIF
      ENDIF
```

So basically you can see it attempts to find a descent direction, if the constraints are active it attempts derivative evaluation along the constraint and fails with a singular matrix in the lsq subproblem (`mode = 6`), then it reasons that if all the constraint equations were evaluated and none yielded successful descent directions, this must be a contradictory set of constraints (`mode = 4`).

Comment: This is really old so can't even check it. Thanks for digging it up anyway.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon can you please explain the hard constraints, again? I need to set constraints of a variable 0<x<1 , and i have no good idea how to enforce that with a transformation.

Comment: @AndreasSchuldei You can use a [sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) to enforce two sided hard constraints.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon can you suggest an effective way to hard constrain sums of search variables, where sum(x1 + x1 + x3...) must be between 0 and 1, individually and in combinations? (I have a few more than 3 that must be hard limited like that. )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75225039/constraining-sums-of-search-variables-to-search-algorithms i opened an other question for this topic