# SciPy - Warning when there are Contradictory constraints?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am using the SciPy package from Python in order to solve a minimization problem with many constraints.

Let's say I have contradictory constraints on my solution. For purposes of this questions, let's just say I had these constraints:

```
 def con1(x):
       return 0.9 * x[0] - x[1]

   def con2(x):
       return 0.9 * x[1] - x[0]
```

With these bounds `[(0.001, None), (0.001, None)]` so that they are both positive.

When I run `scipy.optimize.minimize` with these constraints: `minimize(objective, initial_guess, method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds, constraints=cons)`

Is there any way for scipy to tell me that these are contradictory constraints? As it stands, I either just get a solution which ignores my conditions or a bounds error.

Is there any way for scipy to directly tell me that the conditions cannot be satisfied?

Comment: Which method do you use to minimize the objective function?

Comment: @Corralien Have updated my Question, but it is SLSQP

Comment: Not reproducible until you show code that actually attempts the optimization. Are you checking the success boolean?

Comment: Or the `message` in the `OptimizeResult`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scipy.optimize.minimize method='SLSQP' ignores constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511284/scipy-optimize-minimize-method-slsqp-ignores-constraint) Looks like SLSQP can use mode=4 to signal this  issue.